# I am trying to introduce 'spring-data-jpa-datatables' to my project as a maven dependency, but getting several other errors while starting the server

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jpa-datatables

I am trying to introduce 'spring-data-jpa-datatables' to my project as a maven dependency, but getting several other errors while starting the server

Not sure why I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider`

I added below dependencies to my `pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Created a repository

```
  @Repository("fedGLRepository")
  public interface FedGLRepository extends 
  DataTablesRepository<FedGLVariance, Long> {

  }
```

but after i build and deploy, I get the below Exceptions

```
 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) [spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1112) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.5.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.5.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.5.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.5.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.5.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.5.Final-redhat-3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:309) [spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:285) [spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40) [spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: A stack trace is not a question. Please describe what you did (including the relevant code snippets) and what you are trying to achieve. 
Also, format code and stack traces as code, please.

Comment: @Jens: I am new to Stack Trace, I updated my question, I hope it makes sense to you now

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exception is a sure sign you are having incompatible versions of libraries on your classpath.

Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see how Maven chose between conflicting versions of dependencies. See also the "[Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)"